# bigger mask size for laplacian filter?

Tags: c#, image-processing, mask

I was implementing a simple laplacian filter for an image processing project i was working on. I read that the mask for a 3x3 filter is:

```
+0 -1 +0
-1 +5 -1
+0 -1 +0
```

but i was wondering about the 5x5 mask.. is it:

```
+0 +0 +1 +0 +0
+0 +0 +1 +0 +0
+1 +1 +9 +1 +1    << like a plus (+) sign
+0 +0 +1 +0 +0
+0 +0 +1 +0 +0
```

OR:

```
+0 +0 +1 +0 +0
+0 +1 +1 +1 +0
+1 +1 13 +1 +1    << like a circle
+0 +1 +1 +1 +0
+0 +0 +1 +0 +0
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Mathematica, I obtained the following for the Laplacian and the Laplacian of Gaussian kernels (the latter will be less sensitive to noise). Depending on your application, it may be safe to multiply these masks by an arbitrary positive number. Note that the sum of the coefficients is 0.

[image]

Comment: how to obtain discrete approximation(only int in matrix)?

Comment: @mrgloom It's already a discrete approximation. To have only integers in the matrix, you can divide by the smallest absolute value and then round, and finally make sure the sum of all the elements is zero.  The Laplacian of Gaussian 5x5 kernel could become {{2, 2, 4, 2, 2}, {2, -1, -5, -1, 2}, {4, -5, -16, -5, 
  4}, {2, -1, -5, -1, 2}, {2, 2, 4, 2, 2}}.

Answer (score -1):

5x5 is:

```
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 24 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1
```

It has all edges different then zero, not like a circle.

Comment: isn't the sum of the mask co-officiants is supposed to be one?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you want, and how you want to filter. Try both, see what you like best.

Maybe something like:

```
+0 +0 +1 +0 +0
+0 +3 +5 +3 +0
+1 +5 +9 +5 +1
+0 +3 +5 +3 +0
+0 +0 +1 +0 +0
```

I just made this one up on the fly, and is kinda hemi spherical