# How is discrete laplacian filter kernel computed with arbitrary size?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, filtering, signal-processing, laplacian

I'm implementing the laplacian filter for a depth from focus project, but the laplacian kernel filter with kernel size 3 doesn't work well for my problem. I would like to implement a function that would generate an arbitray sized laplacian kernel.

I did some reseach, and I found [how is Laplacian filter calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544983/how-is-laplacian-filter-calculated), that only explained how laplacian kernel of size 3 is computed.

[bigger mask size for laplacian filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070586/bigger-mask-size-for-laplacian-filter) gives answers for size 5, but doesn't explain why.

Ideally, I'm looking for something like [Sobel filter kernel of large size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567882/sobel-filter-kernel-of-large-size), which explains the sobel kernel with arbitray size very well.

I know OpenCV has an implementation that does it, but I'm curious about the theory behind it. The source code isn't easy to understand.

Comment: If you need a larger filter, you should use Gaussian regularization. This leads to the Lapacian of Gaussian. See here how to compute it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53665075/7328782 — anything else anyone suggest is either not a meaningful extension of the Laplacian, or it has some unwanted properties.

Comment: Isn't LoG same as applying a laplacian filter and a gaussian filter later because of the associativity and commutativity of convolution?

Comment: Yes, it is. The discrete laplacian is a worse approximation than when using proper Gaussian derivative filters, but it works. For larger sigma the error is quite small.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Is there any article that explains this LoG vs discrete laplacian error in more details?

Comment: I don’t know any off the top of my head that discusses this one in particular. But in general a discrete gradient operator is an approximation by definition. The 3x3 Lapace operator is constructed using the discrete approximation to the gradient. In contrast, the Gaussian derivative operator is the derivative of the Gaussian operator, and thus can be used to compute the true (exact) derivative of the smoothed image.